# Sonar extended rule description does not replace default description

Tags: plsql, sonarqube, rule

I'm using Sonar PL/SQL plugin. I updated some Sonar rules (mainly naming convention rules) to be compliant with our coding standard.
So I updated  the regular expression and I added an extended description.

The new regular expression is well taken into account but extended description doesn't replace the default one.

In sonar documentation (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Rules), they say "Note that the extension will be available to non-admin users as a normal part of the rule details." in Rule details section.

Is someone know if it is possible to hide the default rule description because it is not compliant with my new regular expression ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've described the behavior as designed. It is not possible to replace the standard description with your text. Extended descriptions are designed to do just that - *extend* the existing descriptions.

Comment: Ok but result is confusing for users.
Because default description is displayed first and doesn't matched with regular expression updated.
And, sonar documentation says "Note that the extension will be available to non-admin users as **a normal part of the rule details**."

Comment: As default description mentioned "Compliant" and "Non-Compliant" in the code snippet, when rules has been changed we can't keep them.

Is it possible to update default description ?

Comment: Ann, do you have any idea or solution ?
Thanks